# does not run else if condition

Tags: apex, visualforce

when i try my vfp expecting to return 'AVAILABLE'. nothing was displayed. this is my code.

### VFP

```
<apex:pageBlock id="teacherPageBlock">    
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 45px;"> 
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!WrapTS}" var="item" id="teacherBlock">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Teacher" value="{!item.t1.First_Name__c} {!item.t1.Name}"/>
                                <!--   <apex:param id="teacherid" name="teacherId" value="{!item.t1.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedTId}"/> -->
                                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!item.t1.Subject__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Room" value="{!item.t1.Room_Assignment__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Time">
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedTime}">
                                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00AM - 10:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00AM - 11:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00AM - 12:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="12:00PM - 1:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00PM - 2:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00PM - 3:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00PM - 4:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00PM - 5:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!strCheck}">

                                    </apex:outputText>

                                </apex:column>

                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
```

### Controller snippet

```
//CHECK TEACHER SCHEDULE//

public void checkTeacherSched(){
    strCheck = null;
    wrapTeaSched = new list<schedule__c>();

    for(schedule__c myTime : [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c, teacher_cname__c 
        from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c =: myTea AND time__c =: selectedTime ]){
            checkSchedTeaID.add(myTime.id);


       //system.assertequals(checkSchedTeaId + '','test');
       if(checkSchedTeaId!= null){
           strCheck = 'Time selected is no longer available';  
       }
       else if(checkSchedTeaId== null){
           strCheck = 'AVAILABLE';
       }
       }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried adding a system.debug on your strCheck variable after the loop? 

Also, try moving your if else statement for "if(checkSchedTeaID!=null)" outside of the loop

Comment: In constructor or some other part before this method call you are doing checkSchedTeaID = new List<Id>(); that's why checkSchedTeaID  is not null. you can check for (checkSchedTeaID.size() >0) condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1.  make sure you're instanciating checkSchedTeaId by doing

```
checkSchedTeaId = new list<Id>();
```

step 2:  add a debug statement inside your for loop to make sure you're actually returning a result.

step 3: move the null check outside of the loop.  Basically, do something like this:

```
list<schedule__c> myTime = [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c, teacher_cname__c 
    from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c =: myTea AND time__c =: selectedTime ];

if(!myTime.isEmpty()){
       strCheck = 'Time selected is no longer available';  
   }
   else{
       strCheck = 'AVAILABLE';
   }
```

It doesn't look like you're actually using the Id for anything, so you can just evaluate whether or not results were returned.